# Generate .deb from ROS package

Tags: catkin, deb, build-package, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I would like to generate a ".deb" file to share my ROS code with other. I have heard about Bloom and another ways to generate ".deb" files. However, this is not a good solution for me, I only need a local manner to generate a ".deb" file to obfuscate my source code and thereby, my colleague could install and use it in his computer, without see the source.
I only need to share my code with my colleague, no with the ROS community, because it is a very concrete (ad hoc) source code, is not valid for the rest of community.

Is there a "ROS" manner to compile my ROS package in a .deb file?

**Edit (by @William):**

The first step is correct, it generates a `debian` folder with rules and another files.

```
$ cd path/to/your/catkin/package
$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --os-version trusty --ros-distro indigo
```

Then, when i try to use the second command:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

I have problems with CMakeList.txt.

```
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package roscpp.

  Set roscpp_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  roscpp.  The file will have one of the following names:

    roscppConfig.cmake
    roscpp-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package message_generation.

  Set message_generation_DIR to the directory containing a CMake
  configuration file for message_generation.  The file will have one of the
  following names:

    message_generationConfig.cmake
    message_generation-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_message_files):
  Unknown CMake command "add_message_files".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
dh_auto_configure: cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_configure] Error 2
make: *** [binary] Error 2
```

The compiler, among other errors, does not recognize "add_message_files" command.
Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help ;)

---

I am trying with a lot of configurations, but it doesn't work. I am sure that the solution is very simple.
I attach my CMakelist.txt and  package.xml, order that you may check the files.

**CMakelist.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(br_modbus)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp message_generation std_msgs genmsg)


## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
# catkin_python_setup()

#######################################
## Declare ROS messages and services ##
#######################################

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   BrInputStatus.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   setOutput.srv
   setOutputEmpty.srv
   setOutputString.srv
   getOutput.srv
 )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES br_modbus
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
#include/${PROJECT_NAME}

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(br_modbus
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/ClassIOModbusDev.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(ClassIOModbusDev src/ClassIOModbusDev.cpp)
## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(ClassIOModbusDev /usr/lib/libmodbus.so ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(ClassIOModbusDev /usr/lib/libmodbus.so ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

**Package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>br_modbus</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The br_modbus package</description>


  <maintainer email="joseluis@xxx.com">Jose Luis</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->

  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libmodbus-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>genmsg</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>

  <!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-.deb-from-ros-package/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2014-06-17

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can still use bloom to generate the source deb, from which you can build a binary deb:

```
$ cd path/to/your/catkin/package
$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --os-version trusty --ros-distro indigo
```

This will create a folder `debian` with all of the file you need to build a debian. After that you should be able to call something like this:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

To build the `.deb` file (according to this site: https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage).

Node that by using the `bloom-generate rosdebian ...` ROS debian generator, this will setup the package to install into `/opt/ros/<rosdistro>`. If you want it installed into `/usr` you can just use the normal `debian` generator, i.e. replace `rosdebian` with `debian`.

The other option is to just use `checkinstall`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall which I believe can make `.deb` files out of anything which has an install rule.

**Edit:**

You will need to install all dependencies and source the appropriate setup file (usually `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`) before running `fakeroot ...`.

**Edit:**

You can try to use `dpkg-buildpackage` instead:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html

I would just recommend using `checkinstall`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on 2014-06-20**:
As you can see in the CMakelist.txt and package.xml files, I use my own messages and services in my package, this is a trouble for the generation of .deb, as seen in the above mistake:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_message_files):
  Unknown CMake command "add_message_files".
```

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-09-10**:
Calling `bloom-generate rosdebian` is usually enough, distribution and ROS version are guessed automatically.

Is using [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html) a bad idea? It allows to generate debian packages easily, what would be the drawbacks?